# Android AsyncTask Url Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask, httprequest

I am attempting to add a parameter to the JSONPARSER object's makeHttpRequest.  I have a feeling this has to do with the class inheritance, but no luck there.  I am trying to get the DBURL to become a parameter so that I may post data to a database.  I am following this [tutorial][1] on the Register class.  Also, on the onPostExecute method, the MainActivity.this; will not work, only a null value for the first parameter.  Any ideas would be great, and please let me know if you need more information.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final String DBURL = "http:/demo.php";

    //obtain access to jsonparser class functions
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //local initialization of webview
    private WebView webview;
    Context context = this;


    //storage of collected emails, unlimited size
    ArrayList<String> emailsCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    //to later remove duplicate arraylist items, see solution below
    HashSet hashedEmails = new HashSet();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //progress dialog message while loading app resources
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Starting App",true);


        //webview specific settings
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     //   webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
     //   webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     //   webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     //   webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    //creating an instance of the webview client that supports a progress dialog    
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null)
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        //url to load in the webview
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
        //overrides and sets title of app title bar despite original activity name
        setTitle("");



    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        if(file_url !=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(null, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: It won't run because of the errors described above.  The DBURL variable cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_url` will always be null in `postExecute()` because you're not returning anything in your `doInBackground()` method. Parse your JSON response and return it before your catch block.

**EDIT:**
After this line,

```
 Log.d("JSON Status: ", json.toString());
```

Add this:

```
    if (json != null){
        return json.toString();
    }
```

**EDIT2:**

You can't access `DBURL` because it's in a different `Class`.
Change this to public:

```
 public static final String DBURL = "http:/demo.php";
```

And from your `AsyncTask` instead of `DBURL` use `MainActivity.DBURL`

Comment: Thanks.  Am I not parsing the JSON before the catch block?  Should I put return null in the try block?

Comment: @Klinetel No just add a line after 'Log.d' and return json.toString()

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Now could you help with the DBURL access error please?

Comment: @Klinetel Your url cannot be accessed. Are you sure you've setup http:/demo.php properly?

Comment: That was just filler text for what I was planning to do.  Should that matter?  It just needs to access that String, then I will build that script functionality.

Comment: @Klinetel Yes it matters. You're trying to get a response from a service that doesn't exists. What string are you trying to access?

Comment: DBURL.  I am just trying to get the error to go away, then build the script afterwards.  I am not concerned about it running yet.

Comment: @Klinetel The whole point of an AsyncTask is to do something in a background thread (eg: connect to the network). If you want the error to go away you either have to build your script first, or remove this line: JSONObject json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(DBURL, "POST", dbParams); and just return DBURL. But then there is no point in having an AsyncTask in the first place.

Comment: I see what you mean.  But my error is just: "DBURL cannot be resolved to a variable." --It's more simple than what you are describing.

Comment: That solved the access issue, now I have a new error regarding the httprequest: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method makeHttpRequest(String, String, List<NameValuePair>) from the type JSONParser"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37218/discussion-between-klinetel-and-user2045570)

Comment: @Klinetel Remove the static identifier from DBURL. Then in your main method add a static method that returns DBURl. eg: public static String getDBURL(){return DBURL;) and from your AsyncTask call MainActivity.getDBURL()

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `doInBackground()` method is to pass the result of your job (which is executed on a worker thread) to `onPostExecute`, in order to process the result on the UI thread. This is required if you want to update the user interface in response to a successful job run.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an idea as to why the DBURL String cannot be accessed?  Even setting it to public will not work.

Comment: That is problem with scope of the variable.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Define your DBURL inside AysncTask class

Comment: Ok, but then a new error says: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method makeHttpRequest(String, String, List<NameValuePair>) from the type JSONParser"

Comment: write the registerEmails class  with in the MainActivity class

Comment: You can't call something that doesn't exist. Since you haven't created an object, the non-static method doesn't exist yet. A static method (by definition) always exists